# Заменить надпись кнопки Отмена на Скрыть

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предлагаю заменить надпись `Отмена` на `Скрыть`. Потому что она не отменяет ничего. В редакторе вопроса/ответа например кнопка `Отмена` действительно отменяет действие, а тут она просто скрывает блок с фильтром, потому думаю будет правильнее назвать её по назанчению - `Скрыть`

## UPD

После комментария [@EvgeniyZ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12046/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%a1%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c?noredirect=1#comment51924_12046), решил, что будет корректнее показывать "Скрыть" в том случае, если параметры фильтра остались такими же, какие были при открытии блока Фильтр. Ну и показывать "Отмена" в противном случае

## UPD 2

Вопрос закрыт. Этого не было и не будет. [Ссылка на обсуждение](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419040/change-the-label-of-the-cancel-button-to-hide)

Comment: Раз уж пошла такая пьянка, то тогда я за, то чтобы эту кнопку вообще убрали, т.к. фильтры можно банально скрыть снова нажав на кнопку фильтра.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Не уверен, что это очевидное поведение

Comment: А вы попробуйте сделать свой фильтр, сохраните его (сохранить пользовательский фильтр), а потом в списке нажмите ["Править"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XN3X.png), у вас откроется тоже окно, где вы будете редактировать уже ранее созданный фильтр, ну и чего там скрывать собираетесь? "Скрыть фильтр", скрыть от куда? из списка? не применять его? или что? Или все же "Отменить редактирование"? Так что, очень странное исправление будет...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Всегда можно отследить откуда пришла команда. Можно даже более лучший вариант: Если началось редактирование, то кнопка сменяется на "Отмена", а если ничего не менялось или как-то в ходе редактирования были выставлены те же значения что и до этого, то сменяется на "Скрыть"

Comment: Ну, тогда с этими предложениями вам на главный сайт, а не на Ru.SO) На сколько мне известно, то нам доступен лишь перевод, а не функционал, а почему именно переводом замена "Отмены" на "Скрыть" плохо, я вам уже сказал выше.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да, понял, что не очень корректный перевод предложил. А на счёт функционала не знал, что надо именно в SO писать. Я тут просто видел работника ruSO и подумал, что если он заметит, то этого достаточно, чтобы подняли вопрос на эту тему

Comment: `Вопрос закрыт. Этого не было и не будет. ...` - ставьте метку на вопрос: `статус-так-задумано`.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Это надо к модераторам обращаться :)